# Comparision of these types not implemented R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with a column as factors and i am trying to compare them both but it's resulting in an error. What i am doing wrong in here ? The comparison works for element 0 though

```
 Browse[2]> meta['Strip.']
          Strip.
    1 01/03/2017
    2 01/07/2017
    3 01/11/2017
    4 01/05/2017
    Browse[2]> opts['Strip.']
          Strip.
    1 01/03/2017
    2 01/07/2017
    3 01/11/2017
    4 01/05/2017
    Browse[2]> opts[4,'Strip.'] 
    [1] 01/05/2017
    Levels: 01/03/2017 01/05/2017 01/07/2017 01/11/2017
    Browse[2]> meta[4,'Strip.'] 
    [1] 01/05/2017
    Levels: 01/03/2017 01/05/2017 01/07/2017 01/11/2017
    Browse[2]> meta['Strip.'] == opts[4,'Strip.'] 
    Error in meta["Strip."] == opts[4, "Strip."] : 
      comparison of these types is not implemented
    In addition: Warning message:
    Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
```

My Full comparison to extract the same line and i have for loop to iterate through i.

```
  meta.line <- meta[ meta['Strip.'] == opts[i, 'Strip.'] &meta['Contract_type.'] == opts[i, 'Contract_type.'] & meta['Strike.'] == opts[i,'Strike.'], ]
```

Comment: I am trying to match two data frames and return the columns that match the same line. how can i extract the same line ?

Comment: You need to make sure that objects you are comparing are of the same type (or can be coerced into the same). Convert  your columns to dates with `as.Date`.